Asking about a proof for a theorem that strengthens Schur's theorem
Let $ n \in \mathbb{N}^* $. Each positive integer is painted with one of $ n $ colors.
Prove that there exist three positive integers $ a, b, c $ (not necessarily distinct) painted with the same color among these $ n $ colors such that $ a = b + c $.
The same requirement as in question (1) but with a stricter requirement that $ a, b, c $ are pairwise distinct.
My idea is to translate this into graph theory. I have the following result:
For each $ n \in \mathbb{N}^* $, there exists a positive integer $ s(n) $ such that the complete graph $ K_{s(n)} $ with edges painted in one of $ n $ colors contains a $ K_3 $ with all three edges painted the same color.
Define the sequence $ \{s(n)\} $ as follows (there are many ways to choose $ s(n+1) $, but the idea is to select $ s(n+1) $ large enough so that among $ s(n+1) - 1 $ edges, there exists at least one color that is assigned to at least $ s(n) $ edges):
$$
   s(1) = 3, \quad s(n+1) = (n+1)\left[s(n) - 1\right] + 2, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*.
   $$
By induction, I have shown that if $ K_{s(n)} $ is painted with $ n $ colors, then it contains a $ K_3 $ with all three edges painted the same color.
Returning to the problem, let the $ n $ colors of the given problem be $ c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n $.
Consider the complete graph $ K_{s(n)} $ (with $ s(n) $ constructed as above) with vertices labeled $ \{1, 2, \ldots, s(n)\} $.
We color the edges of $ K_{s(n)} $ as follows:
The edge connecting vertices $ i $ and $ j $ (where $ 1 \le i < j \le s(n) $) is painted with color $ c_k $, where $ c_k $ is the color assigned to the integer $ j - i $.
According to the result above, there exist three vertices $ i, j, k $ with $ i < j < k $ such that the edges $ ij, jk, ki $ are all painted the same color. In other words, three numbers $ b = j - i $, $ c = k - j $, and $ a = k - i $ are painted the same color. Checking shows that $ a = b + c $. The problem is therefore proven.
I am still unsure how to prove the existence of distinct $ a, b, c $ that satisfy $ a = b + c $.

Does the following work? $a,b,c$ are not distinct iff $2j = i+k$. Instead of indexing your complete graph using ${1, \dots, s(n)}$, choose a set $A$ of $s(n)$ integers such that one never has $2a_1 = a_2 + a_3$ for some distinct $a_1, a_2, a_3 \in A$. (This can be done; the set ${2^{0}, 2^{1}, \dots, 2^{s(n)}
}$ works, for example.) Index your graph using $A$ instead and
run your argument again, coloring the edge $j-i$ with the color assigned to the integer $j-i$.
